# Tab Menu in prime ng

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, primeng

I want to load a component template in tab menu click.

```
<p-tabMenu class="ui-tabmenu" [model]="items"></p-tabMenu>

this.items = [
    {label: 'Contacts', icon: 'fa-bar-chart'},
    {label: 'Call Logs', icon: 'fa-calendar'} 
];
```

This is my code. It shows two menu contacts and call logs. when I click on conatct menu I want to load `contactcomponent.html` and when click on call logs menu load `calllogscomponent.html`. How can I implement this?

Comment: Same problem. PrimeNG's doc is desperately poor. It tells how to make the tabs themselves, but not a word about how to display content or switch between different templates. I'm currently spending my whole days trying to figure out how to use PrimeNG components.

Answer (score 12):

If this is your top-level menu (or you want the main page URL to be set) then consider using the router. This will automatically sync with the current 'page' set in the router:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menumodel

```
export class MenuDemo implements OnInit {

    private items: MenuItem[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [{
            label: 'File',
            items: [
                {label: 'New', icon: 'fa-plus', url: 'http://www.primefaces.org/primeng'},
                {label: 'Open', icon: 'fa-download', routerLink: ['/pagename']}
            ]
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<p-tabMenu #menuItems [model]="items" [activeItem]="activeItem" (click)="activateMenu()"></p-tabMenu>

items:MenuItem[];
activeItem: MenuItem;
@ViewChild('menuItems') menu: MenuItem[];

this.items = [
    {label: 'Contacts', icon: 'fa-bar-chart'},
    {label: 'Call Logs', icon: 'fa-calendar'} 
];
this.activeItem = this.items[0];

activateMenu(){
   this.activeItem =this.menu['activeItem'];
}
```

Create template reference variable **#menuItems** and use it in ts to do modifications on that template.On click of another menu it triggers **activateMenu()** function where it sets the new selected menu as an active one.In html toggle between two menu using ***ngIf** comparing with the ***activeItem.label***.

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, what you are looking for is the TabView component: https://primeng.org/tabview.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation of Primeng TabMenu there is not such functionality given by them you can only set attribute there is not a single callback function by default for the same

Source:- * https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tabmenu

Instead you can use `breadcrumb` for redirecting page there you can provide URL too, than style that breadcrumb according to your need with css

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/breadcrumb

## Update

- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menumodel

you can use this there you can call callback function and navigation as well in menu

Comment: then how to show contents dependent on tab menu click. can you please give one example like that.

Comment: please see Updated answer